# Python Json file error when trying to refer to json file to save to

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```
def state_manager(self, action):

    # Define initialized state, default values.
    initialized_state = {'access_token': None,
                         'refresh_token': None,
                         'token_expires_at': 0,
                         'authorization_url': None,
                         'redirect_code': None,
                         'token_scope': '',
                         'loggedin': False}

    dir_path = r"C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\TDClient"
    filename = 'TDAmeritradeState.json'
    file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, filename)

    # if the state is initialized
    if action == 'init':
        self.state = initialized_state

        # if allowed cache load the file
        if self.config['cache_state'] and os.path.isfile(file_path):
            with open(file_path, 'r') as fileHandle:
                self.state.update(json.load(fileHandle))

        # If not allowed cache delete file
        elif not self.config['cache_state'] and os.path.isfile(file_path):
            os.remove(file_path)

        # save and cache allowed load file
    elif action == 'save' and self.config['cache_state']:
        with open(file_path, 'w') as fileHandle:
            # Build JSON string using dictionary comprehension.
            json_string = {key:self.state[key] for key in initialized_state}

            json.dump(json_string, fileHandle)
```

Full Trace Back:

```
> File "C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\TDClient\TDApi.py", line 47, in __init__
> self.state_manager('init') File
> "C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\TDClient\TDApi.py", line 101, in state_manager
> self.state.update(json.load(fileHandle)) File
> "C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py",
> line 293, in load return loads(fp.read(), File
> "C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py",
> line 357, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File
> "C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py",
> line 337, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
> File
> "C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py",
> line 355, in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s,
> err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value:
> line 1 column 1 (char 0) Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Hello, I am receiving this error, when I place the `file_path` into my code. When I put anything else into the `os.path.isfile()`, no error occurs. But when I reference my directory to the json file I want to save it to, it returns this error.

The information I am receiving is from `TDameritrade`, and it is in json format I believe, I do not know what am I doing wrong, and im referencing the directory incorrectly?

Comment: The content of the file is not valid JSON.

Comment: This is just a blank file tho, I am using it to store the info I receive back from the tdapi which is json, It only gives me a error when I try to use this function with the full directory, when I the filename variable, it gives no errors, and runs fine, except it won't save into the blank json file that I am referencing to.

Comment: You will receive the given error if you try to parse a blank file.

Answer (score 0):

**Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

Seems it fails while trying to parse empty JSON

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve pulled JSON data in from another program or have otherwise obtained a string of JSON formatted data in Python, deserialize that with `loads()` instead of `load()`